# Is there a way to select which types of HTTP requests are logged by pyramid_debugtoolbar?

Tags: python, pyramid, pyramid-debug-toolbar

I am trying to check performance on an app that is hosted behind a haproxy load balancer.  The load balancer is currently checking service health by sending a HEAD query to the root uri `/`.  Because this happens once a second, the legitimate requests scroll off the list pretty quickly.

Is there a way that I can selectively disable logging of HEAD requests?

Comment: It is definitely possible. However I think some of the elements in this question are missing. How do you run Pyramid? Also Pyramid debug toolbar is a client side component and most likely not involved in logging at all.